# string data isn't being sent to main acitivity

Tags: listview, android-studio

I am trying to send strings to my listview. Sadly, the data isn't getting sent over and shows no errors. Main activity has the list view, where a user clicks a button (takes them to the second activity) where they can enter the products name and the should automatically take them back to the main activity.

This did work at one point, but I must of messed something up. Am I missing something?

MainActivity.java

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private ListView listView;
        private String[] details;
        public static ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    // replace \ with left angle bracket in the line below
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(

                    new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        }
                    }
                );
            }

    }
```

Second Activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {
    private EditText textName;
    private EditText textModel;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        textName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        textModel=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inpuModelNumber);



    }
    public void addNames(View v){
        MainActivity.names.add(textName.getText().toString());

        finish();
    }


}
```

Comment: where you call addNames ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I understand you want pass array list of string to another activity

create arraylist in your activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {
    private EditText textName;
    private EditText textModel;
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        textName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        textModel=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inpuModelNumber);

    } 
    public void addNames(View v){
       names.add(textName.getText().toString());

       Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity .this, MainActivity .class);
       intent.putStringArrayListExtra("keyNames", names);
       startActivity(intent);
       finish();

    } 
}
```

then parse passed array of strings

in oncreate

```
 Intent i = getIntent();  
    ArrayList<String> list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("keyNames");
```

I hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

```
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(

                    new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

Intent newPage = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
        Main2Activity.class);
newPage.putExtra("TITLE", title);
newPage.putExtra("DATE", date);
newPage.putExtra("CONTENT", content);
startActivity(newPage);


                        }
                    }
                );
            }
```

Then in your Main2Activity's onCreate() method:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras !=null) {
    String title = extras.getString("TITLE");
    String date = extras.getString("DATE");
    String content = extras.getString("CONTENT");
}
```